# Is there any Javascript project that compiles "asynchronous->synchronous" code (eg, Streamline.js) to standalone Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I love Streamline.js (https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs), which allows you to write blocks of js code which don't indent, but which block until their normally asynchronous calls resolve:

```
console.log('hello ...');
setTimeout(_, 1000);
console.log('... world');
```

But with Streamline, the code above compiles into js code which requires tons of complex dependencies. It's not clear to me that it's even possible to run the code Streamline produces outside of Node.

Is there any Javascript project that compiles "asynchronous->synchronous" code to standalone Javascript? Or Javascript which only requires inclusion of a library through standard < script> tags?

Comment: You're looking for https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#synchronous-to-asynchronous-javascript-compilers-cps

Comment: It looks like Streamline can be made to run its compiled JS in a standalone way, or something close to it, but I haven't found anything that compiles to fully standalone code.